# SourceTree cannot access remote repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree v2.3.1 on Windows 7 alongside VisualStudio 2017 v15.3.5. I updated both SourceTree and Visual Studio to these version recently, and possibly as a result of one or both of the updates, I have been unable to use SourceTree to Push, Pull, Fetch or any other operation against a remote TFS/Git repository.

When I try, I get an error like:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I have tried reinstalling SourceTree, removing all temporary files relating to it, installing keys in Putty, rebooting; all to no avail.
I can perform remote repository operations using Visual Studio's built in GIT client.

Please can you tell me what I need to do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried updating Git itself? When I had this problem it was something to do with my embedded version of Git being out of date.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the embedded version of Git in SourceTree? I'm not actually using that, though I was thinking of trying it.

Comment: Yes in my case it was the embedded version that was the problem (for some reason updating SourceTree did not update the version of Git it had embedded) - if you are using system Git you could try updating that